# ListView scroll calls again the adapter

Tags: android, listview

When I scroll a ListView why it calls again it corresponding adapter?

I need to avoid this because it produces a lag when I scroll my ListView

Does anyone what can I do?

**Edit:** This is my Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MatchDTO> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<MatchDTO> matches) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, matches);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup mainViewGroup) {

        try {

            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.matches_list, null);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.homeGoals = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_goals);
                viewHolder.awayGoals = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.away_goals);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            MatchDTO match = matches.get(position);

            viewHolder.homeGoals.setText(String.valueOf(match.getHomeGoals()));
            viewHolder.awayGoals.setText(String.valueOf(match.getAwayGoals()));

        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        TextView homeGoals;
        TextView awayGoals;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use a view holser?

Comment: Yes, I use a ViewHolder

Comment: post the adapter code

Comment: Ready. I post it in the question

Comment: your adapter looks fine unless i am missing something

Comment: When you scroll the listview, it will need to call the adapter to inflate the next rows. Paste your full activity code too

Comment: @JohnB you can move this to the constructor `inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)`. initialize `inlfater`  in the constructor of custom adapter

Comment: MatchesViewHolder - what is this class doing in the adapter when you have a ViewHolder class already defined ?

Comment: Excuse me @RahulGupta I fix this. It was an copy and paste error

Answer (score 0):

Please read this http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

and add `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` where you have called he CustomAdapter class in your main activity

Comment: `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` is used to refresh listview. so why is this required unless you are changing the underlying data that populates listview?

Comment: After read this article that you suggests now I can understand your comment in my question (When you scroll the listview, it will need to call the adapter to inflate the next rows. Paste your full activity code too) Thanks @RahulGupta. I am still reading the article. It is excellent